# После компиляции получается разделяемая библиотека

Tags: c, компиляция, gcc

Изучаю язык Си и столкнулся с вопросом, на который так и не смог найти ответа. После написания небольшой программки я компилирую ее с помощью gcc следующей командой: 
`gcc prog.c -o prog` 
На выходе получается файл без расширения, который я запускаю командой `./prog`

Вопрос следующий: Если я перехожу в свойства файла, то там написано, что файл является разделяемой библиотекой. Почему он помечает его так? Если я захожу в файлы какой-то программы, например телеграм, то там есть файл, который помечен как исполняемый и при двойном щелчке предлагает его запустить. Как сделать то же самое с моей программой?

ОС LUbuntu 18.04

Comment: *файл без разрешения* - без расширения? :)

Comment: @Harry, Да,  точно)

Comment: В терминале `chmod +x prog`?

Comment: @EOF, Нет, это другое. Файл исполняется и все с ним в порядке. Вопрос в том, почему в свойствах файла написано, что это разделяемая библиотека.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я нашел ответ. Это происходит из-за включенной по умолчанию технологии в компиляторе, которая называется ASLR. Чтобы ее выключить, нужно использовать флаг -no-pie. Тогда получается исполняемый файл. Больше информации есть на англоязычном сайте: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519521/why-does-gcc-create-a-shared-object-instead-of-an-executable-binary-according-to/55704865#55704865

Answer (score 1):

[Как в Clion собирать проект в исполняемый файл вместо разделяемой библиотек](https://www.khtulhu.org.ua/veb-programmirovanie/1065-kak-v-clion-sobirat-proekt-v-ispolnyaemyj-fajl-vmesto-razdelyaemoj-biblioteki.html)

```
SET(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-no-pie")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
```

Надо вот это добавить в CMakeList.txt